# Forced download of image raw data is corrupted on android 2.3

Tags: php, javascript, mobile-website

I'm trying to develop a mechanism to download a canvas as an image by forcing download via php. the following code works in chrome desktop but NOT on an Android 2.3 stock browser.

#### HTML & JavaScript:

```
<script> function downloadImage()
{

    document.getElementById('action').value = 'downloadfile';
    document.getElementById('source').value = document.getElementById('finalimage').src;
    document.getElementById('user').value = userId;
    document.getElementById('imageForm').submit();
}
</script>
<html>
    <form id="imageForm" action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="source" id="source" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="savefile"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value=""/>
    </form>
</html>
```

#### PHP Code:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"colouringbook-page.jpg\"");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");

        $source = $_REQUEST['source'];
        $source = base64_decode(substr($source, strpos($source, ",")+1));
        header("Content-Length: " . strlen($source));
        print $source;
        exit;
?>
```

The problem I am getting is firstly a "Download unsuccessful". Then when I DO manage to get a successful download the image is corrupted.

### [Update]

### I am testing by just outputting to browser then trying to save the image from there. I'm getting the image displayed but in saving the image the file naming scheme is *.html

Looks like it can be an android stock browser bug. I was able to save the image to the server but still couldn't output the buffer from there to download the image. I had to output a regular html  tag then do a "save as" on the android to download the image.

Comment: Why are you sending `application/octet-stream` when you are forcing a .jpg download? Should be `image/jpeg`.

Comment: whether its application/octet-stream or image/jpeg...Its not working. It was suggested to go application/octet-stream to allow android to auto detect what kind of file it is. Also how am I allowing for directory attacks? There is not file or directory reading or writing?

Comment: Sorry I misread the source of `$source`. Without seeing an example of the input data, it is hard to envision what is being posted.  `finalimage` looks like it's probably a base64 image string?

Comment: Yes it is...it works in Chrome Desktop. But I can't understand why not in Android 2.3 stock browser. I'm beginning to think there is some base64 encoding bug in Android. I will send you a link in private?

Comment: I do happen to have an Android 2.3 device. You can't really send a private link. You can put in a comment then delete it. I can check it in my phone, but I'm not sure what help it would be.

Comment: Would be nicer if you had Android 3 or 4

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21850/discussion-between-kendall-and-michael-berkowski)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats seems to be happening is that the Android device is attempting to "re-request" the process which is POSTED logic process. Apparently the device download manager doesn't POST anything.

The solution I came up with was to use a session to store the information

Answer (score 1):

I recently have some troubles with managing HTTP headers : be sure you have not a module which compress data before sending (ex : mod_deflate for apache2). When you send your HTTP answer, you indicate is lenght with header("Content-Length: " . strlen($source));
This length is False if you use compression. Maybe Android browser still waiting datas and finally close image considering it corrupted.

If it's your problem, you can try to shutdown compression on this script (ex for apache2 : apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');)
Or you can try to NOT send a Content-Length information.

EDIT : You should use the true mimetype to better help Android to manage your image.